# back button return the application to inconsistent state

Tags: android, android-activity

Today I was testing my app (wich is a very simple note application) but some strange behaviour occur .

- The app consists of a big ListView which displays all the notes and a button to make a new note (activity A).
- When I press the button to "Add new note",it takes me to the activity B
  (with all the fields like title and text).
- When I press "Add" ,it take me back to the activity A and displays ok
  the new Note .

The thing is that I started pressing BACK and it began to take me "back in time" where some notes were still not created,until it reached the time they were 0 notes .

Since I am new to Android devel ,is this normal or is it something wrong with my app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you go from one activity to another then you should finish your activity and then start new activity.
Try the below code:

```
finish();
startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NewActivity.class));
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay .I will give it a shot ,but as far as I know finish() is used when you started the Activity with startActivityForResult() .It is advise to used in the way you are saying ?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to implement some sort of refresh method to update your ListView.  Depending on how you are persisting the data, you could create a method that retrieves the latest data and then updates the adapter for the ListView.  Once you have that implemented, you should call the method in `onResume()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,i will try it now .My data is stored in a sqlite database

Comment: Hope that helps! I'll check back later just in case.

Comment: yes that's it @visceral , he just need to add some function of refresh from the database , so the last data stored on his SQlite Database will be displayed on the ListView

Comment: I just tried it and it still performs the same. May be the error is because after i add to the data base the new note ,from the Activity B I call Activity A with an Intent ,so maybe Android creates another Activity A ,a new one :/ ...... may be ,but I am not sure .